# What goes into a realistic wood material?

Tags: unity, materials

Aside from getting a wood texture to use for albedo, what goes into a realistic wood material? For example, in Unity, there are settings such as Metallic and Smoothness, and different shader types which have other settings such as Specular.

What are the best settings to use for wood to make it look realistic? Just by guessing I would think that wood would have a low amount of Metallic and a low amount of Smoothness, but I'm not sure what shader to use, or what values to use.

Just as an example, we can focus on one particular type of wood, such as Oak.

Comment: Think about all the wooden objects you've seen in your lifetime. Or even just all the objects made of oak — with or without bark, chopped or sanded, stained or varnished. Do they all look the same? Are some of them smoother than others? If so, then you'll need to narrow this question down: show us a sample of the wood you want to imitate, and a screenshot of your best attempt so far to replicate that specific wood in Unity. Then we can suggest what to change to make a better match for that specific wood finish.

Comment: with metal, you usually either have 0, or 1.  An object is either metal or it isn't.  also, i think a good bump map is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google some wood pictures and try to match them. I know that sounds simple. And that's because it is simple as a concept. If you're unfamiliar with some terms, such as specular (light reflectivity), Google them as well so you have a grasp of what settings you're changing.

Natural wood is dull. However, a painted deck on a house or lacquered computer desk, may appear shinier than some metals. Wood also usually has micro-grooves in it which is what normal mapping is used for. Just like my lacquered desk example, some wood could be very smooth as well.